# how to load a component programatically to one div in angular 2

Tags: angular

i am very new to angular 2, 
i have some set of dynamically created divs i want to load per-defined components to those div based on user selection. i tried many blogs to load component dynamically but none of them are clear and simple.

what i'am expecting is to know how to load one component to a div on click of a button.

for example

```
@Component({
    selector: 'container',
    template: `<div id="container">// need to place the component here on click of a button  //</div>`
 })
```

if anybody can provide a plunker or solution is highly appreciated

Comment: There is one of Q & A how to do dynamic stuff http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310

Comment: Here is the same stuff https://medium.com/nerdlog/angular-2-dynamic-view-and-components-330205fa6896#.yqf9wocpv

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. it seems very complex is there any other simple example anybody can give ? like i said on click of a button it should load a component on the container

Answer (score -2):

Define a html component using # inside template

```
<div #container ></div>
```

Now you can access this container inside the component class

```
this.container.innerHTML="YOUR CONTENT";
```

Comment: You forgot to define a `@ViewChild('container')`, without that there is no reference to `#container`